# Why does a challenge validation fail between WebAuthn server (go) and client (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, go, encoding, decoding, webauthn

I am developing a client server application. The server portion is written in pure Go, using the go-webauthn/webauthn library. The client side is pure JavaScript.

Currently I have implemented a register begin and register finish hook, which already does some communication.

When a user logs in with his/her web browser, it is possible to register a webauthn device. By clicking the butten, a dialog appears and I can touch the sensor of my Yubikey. After that data is sent to the server, which parses the data and does validation. Unfortunately this fails!

As I am very new to JavaScript, I have spent hours and hours and this is my current draft:

```js
const register_device = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const buffer_encode = array_buffer => {
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(array_buffer)))
            .replace(/\+/g, "-")
            .replace(/\//g, "_")
            .replace(/=/g, "");
    }

    const buffer_decode = array_buffer => {
        return Uint8Array.from(array_buffer, c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    }

    // Check whether current browser supports WebAuthn
    if (!window.PublicKeyCredential) {
        alert("Error: this browser does not support WebAuthn");

        return;
    }

    let status_code

    // The username is stored in a cookie. Start the registration process...
    await fetch("/2fa/v1/webauthn/register/begin")
        .then(async response => {
            const credentialCreationOptions = await response.json();

            // console.log(credentialCreationOptions.publicKey.challenge);

            credentialCreationOptions.publicKey.challenge = buffer_decode(
                credentialCreationOptions.publicKey.challenge
            );
            credentialCreationOptions.publicKey.user.id = buffer_decode(
                credentialCreationOptions.publicKey.user.id
            );

            return navigator.credentials.create({
                publicKey: credentialCreationOptions.publicKey
            })
        })
        .then(async credential => {
            let attestationObject = credential.response.attestationObject;
            let clientDataJSON = credential.response.clientDataJSON;
            let rawId = credential.rawId;

            /*
            // Decode the clientDataJSON into a utf-8 string
            const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
            const decodedClientData = utf8Decoder.decode(clientDataJSON);

            // Parse the string as an object
            const clientDataObj = JSON.parse(decodedClientData);

            console.log(clientDataObj)
            */

            return await fetch("/2fa/v1/webauthn/register/finish", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: credential.id,
                    rawId: buffer_encode(rawId),
                    type: credential.type,
                    response: {
                        attestationObject: buffer_encode(attestationObject),
                        clientDataJSON: buffer_encode(clientDataJSON),
                    }
                })
            })
        })
        .then (async response => {
            status_code = response.status;

            return await response.json()
        })
        .then (result => {
            console.log(`Registration result: code=${status_code} message=${result}`);
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error(`An error occurred when registering the user: ${error}`);
        });
}

device.addEventListener("click", register_device);
```

I have a best guess:

I really have no idea what it is about the buffer_encode and buffer_decode functions. It does work in some way, but I think it breaks something.

What I am not understanding is, why do I need these .replace()-statements in the buffer_enocde routine? Why does it not work at all, if I am removing these lines?

Is there someone, who can show me a correct buffer_encode and buffer_decode function, so that the rest of the webauthn stuff works correctly?

Currently the server returns at the finish hook that the validation failed.

```golang
    response, err := protocol.ParseCredentialCreationResponseBody(ctx.Request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())

        return
    }

    credential, err := webAuthn.CreateCredential(user, *sessionData, response)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())

        return
    }
```

I use go-webauthn/webauthn with go-gingonic.

CreateCredential() throws the error I am asking about.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Those .replace()-statements are converting the buffer to URL safe base64 encoding without padding.

Are there any exceptions being raised out of the server library?  There should be some clues coming from the server.

Comment: Also, have you seen https://github.com/go-webauthn/example?

Comment: Thanks for the example repo. I lokked into it and I grabbed to ProtoErrToFields-method. Here is, what the result error looks like:
```
Registration result: code=400 message=[{Key:err Type:26 Integer:0 String: Interface:Error validating challenge} {Key:details Type:15 Integer:0 String:Error validating challenge Interface:<nil>} {Key:info Type:15 Integer:0 String:Expected b Value: "roLau8pXNhIromdBNn6s3POQOFAwcmcV9s8PV53shRk"
Received b: "cm9MYXU4cFhOaElyb21kQk5uNnMzUE9RT0ZBd2NtY1Y5czhQVjUzc2hSaw"
 Interface:<nil>} {Key:type Type:15 Integer:0 String:verification_error Interface:<nil>}]
```

Comment: @aseigler As you see: b received and b stored are different and I can not figure out why

Answer (score 0):

The challenges don't match. The second string (`cm9MYXU4cFhOaElyb21kQk5uNnMzUE9RT0ZBd2NtY1Y5czhQVjUzc2hSaw`) is a base64 encoded version of the first string (`roLau8pXNhIromdBNn6s3POQOFAwcmcV9s8PV53shRk`):

[https://cyberchef.org/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',false,false)&input=Y205TVlYVTRjRmhPYUVseWIyMWtRazV1Tm5NelVFOVJUMFpCZDJOdFkxWTVjemhRVmpVemMyaFNhdw](https://cyberchef.org/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,false,false)&input=Y205TVlYVTRjRmhPYUVseWIyMWtRazV1Tm5NelVFOVJUMFpCZDJOdFkxWTVjemhRVmpVemMyaFNhdw)

Don't double base64 encode the challenge.

Comment: @seigler, first of all thanks to find the main issue. Can you show me an example for the buffer_encode and/or buffer_decode that solves the problem? I still have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: The example site does a good job of showing how to do this: https://github.com/go-webauthn/example/blob/fb474ba04d9fe923e26e8785d651fbeba3679667/src/services/WebauthnService.ts#L304